# Basecamp API classic - Order people by name (alphabetically)

Tags: php, api, alphabetical, basecamp

I'm retrieving a list of people via Basecamp API classic, except it seems to come ordered by ID. I followed the documentation to do so, here is a simplified version of the echoing part:

```
foreach($persons as $person) {
    $firstName = $person->getFirstname();
    $lastName = $person->getLastname();

    echo $firstName.' '.$lastName;
}
```

Any idea how I could order this list by alphabetical order?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort()` function on $persons

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

EDIT: Oh, wait, can you show a `print_r()` of $persons?

Comment: I tried that, it outputs the following error: "Warning: sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object".

Comment: Yeah, I realised that with my edit. Please provide the print_r or var_dump of $persons.